# Removing columns with equals sum from dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dynamic table that generates columns named seriesX (X a number based on the number of incidents) and want to do 2 things:
First, remove one of the columns with the sum(column) equals and after that, rename all the columns to keep the number sequential in the seriesX.

Is that a way to accomplish this?

Example

```
series1 series2 series3 series4 series5 series6 series7 series8 series9 series10 series11
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 3.23333 
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 3.23333 
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 3.23333 
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 2.55333 
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 1.87333
```

I want to remove all the columns with the same sum (in this case 0) and rename the series11 column to series1

in the end, would have only this:

```
series1 
---------
3.23333 
3.23333 
3.23333 
2.55333 
1.87333
```

Comment: This seems like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. This is not how relational data works. You would have to use dynamic sql here to even get started.

Comment: How did you come up with this result in the first place? You need to fix it there.

Comment: Listen to the comments of Sean and Salman please, Lucas. What you ask is very complicated. Without providing a full answer, you would have to 1.Get all the seriesXX column names from sys.columns into a table. 2.Add another column that you fill with a cursor/while loop of running a dynamic sql count distinct value on each column 3. delete where the new column has value=1 4.Create a new dynamic sql query, the column names you draw data from will be the originals left in the table you made and the new column names will be a comma-seperated concatenation of a row_number() of the table's rows.